# How do I add a 2 Digit number inside an Array as a single entry using getch()?

Tags: c

I've got this example which I made but it doesn't work.
This code is supposed to add XX:YY:ZZ to an array that has 3 columns: realtime = {XX, YY, ZZ}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    int realtime[3];
    char time[8];
    for(int i = 0;i<8;i++){
        time[i] = getche();
    }
    for(int i = 0, j = 0;i<3;i++, j+=3){
        realtime[i] = (time[j])*10+time[j+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide what behavior you expect and what you're getting.  Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help.

Comment: `i++, j+=3` - this looks really broken

Comment: `time` is a well known function.  Code should not be redefining well known functions as some array.

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is non-standard.  Strongly suggest removing that header file from your program and using the standard C library functions (for instance: `getchar()`)  when programming.

Comment: the posted code is making some wildly bad assumptions.  Such as the idea that the user will input 8 consecutive characters in the format: XX:YY:ZZ.  Never trust user input.  Always verify the values entered

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the character `'0'` does **not** have the integer value `0`. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

The integer value of the character `'0'` is normally 48. So if you read the text string "01:23:45", you'll end up with `time[0]` having the integer value 48, `time[1]` having the integer value 49, `time[3]` having the integer value 50  and so on.

Therefore you need to subtract 48 to the values in `time` in the second loop. That is normally done by: `time[j]-'0'`.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0;i<3;i++, j+=3){
    realtime[i] = ((time[j]-'0')*10+(time[j+1]-'0');
                   //      ^^^^               ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Or simply do `time[i] = getch()-'0';`.